# Botões feitos com imagens

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com uma dúvida. Recentemente entrei [nesse site](http://levelupgames.uol.com.br/elsword/era-dos-herois/) aqui e percebi que logo no começo havia uns botões com formato diferentes dei uma olhada e percebi que eram imagens e que possuía um efeito `:hover`.

Achei muito interessante, dei uma inspecionada e mesmo assim não entendi como que ele foi feito, então gostaria de saber se alguém pode me explicar como foi feito porque em um arquivo de imagem tem vários botões.

Se vocês derem um inspecionar elemento verão isso, porém não compreendo como conseguiram, por exemplo, deixar o botão um embaixo do outro, fora o `:hover`  que nem sei como conseguiram fazer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O efeito não utiliza nenhum recurso CSS3 ou HTML5, mas eu utilizarei mostrar como o efeito funciona.

```css
a{
    background-image: url(http://levelupgames.uol.com.br/elsword/era-dos-herois/img/menu-vertical.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -168px 0;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    width: 168px;
    height: 48px;
    font-family: 'carter_oneregular';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 43px;
}
a:hover{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
a:active{
    background-position: 0 -48px;
}
a.efeito{
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: background-position 1s;
}
```

```html
<a>Normal</a>
<hr>
<a class="efeito">"Câmera Lenta"</a>
```

O efeito consiste em reposicionar a imagem do fundo.

[image: Imagem do Background]

No elemento o `background-position` dele está definido como `-168px` que é a metade da largura da imagem, onde começa os quadros cinzas e na regra `:hover` ele seta como `background-position: 0 0;` que é no início da imagem.

Um ponto importante é a largura e altura, que devem ser do tamanho do quadro utilizado, nesse caso `width: 168px; height:48px;`.

Essa técnica é conhecida como Sprites, amplamente [utilizado no desenvolvimento de jogos 2D](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=sprites&tbm=isch), mas também aplicado na web.

Você pode ler mais a respeito nessa [postagem do Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/css-sprites/).

Comment: obrigado simplesmente fantastico sua explicação e resolução simples e rapido obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro vc cria uma imagem com duas transições conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
 _______________
|+++++++++++++++|
|++++ligado+++++|
|_______________|
|---------------|
|---desligado---|
|_______________|
```

Vamos imaginar que essa imagem tenha: 90px x 120px, ou seja, a metade dela na horizontal equivale á 60px.

```
<style> 
#elemento a {
   background: url('url_da_imagem.jpg') top left no-repeat;
   width: 90px;
   height: 60px;
   display:block;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
#elemento a:hover {
   background: url('url_da_imagem.jpg') bottom left no-repeat;
}
#elemento span {
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

Observe que a imagem foi reposicionada no css, de [top] para [bottom] respeitando a área do tamanho da metade da imagem:

```
<div id="elemento">
   <a href="#"><span>ligado | desligado</span></a>
</div>
```

Você também pode em vez de usar top, e bottom, usar um número relativo ao tamanho, tipo: de [0px] para [-60px].